# Constructor chaining with Reflection.Emit / Sigil

Tags: c#, cil, reflection.emit

I'm trying to create a class like the following using [Sigil](https://github.com/kevin-montrose/Sigil) which is a wrapper around Reflection.Emit.

```
public class Test
{
    public Test(string arg1)
    {
    }

    public Test() : this("arg1") 
    {
    }
}
```

Using the following Code I keep getting the Exception: "The invoked member is not supported before the type is created."

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using Sigil.NonGeneric;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var asmName = new AssemblyName("MyAssembly");
        var asm = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(asmName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Save);

        var mod = asm.DefineDynamicModule(asmName.Name, asmName.Name + ".dll");

        var test = mod.DefineType("Test", TypeAttributes.Public);

        // special constructor
        var ctorBuilder1 = Emit.BuildConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(string) }, test, MethodAttributes.Public);
        ctorBuilder1.Return();
        var ctor1 = ctorBuilder1.CreateConstructor();

        // default constructor calling the special one
        var ctorBuilder2 = Emit.BuildConstructor(new Type[] { }, test, MethodAttributes.Public);
        ctorBuilder2.LoadArgument(0);
        ctorBuilder2.LoadConstant("arg1");
        ctorBuilder2.Call(ctor1); // Exception thrown here
        ctorBuilder2.Return();
        var ctor2 = ctorBuilder2.CreateConstructor();

        test.CreateType();
        asm.Save(asmName.Name + ".dll");
    }
}
```

I read about using ´DynamicMethod´ but got the Error "Delegate of type Sigil.Impl.NonGenericPlaceholderDelegate takes no parameters" when I replaced my `BuildConstructor` call with the following:

```
var piCtor = Emit.NewDynamicMethod(pi, new Type[] {}, ".ctor", mod);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is `Emit` here? Could you provide a [mcve] so that we can easily reproduce the issue? (With the arguments you've given, I could understand `test.DefineConstructor`, but not `Emit.BuildConstructor`.)

Comment: @DaisyShipton I've just added usings to make it clear.

Comment: Ah, I assume it's `Sigil` which was confusing me in that case. I'll have a look when I get a chance, but it now won't be for a couple of hours. (It would still be generally more helpful if you'd provide complete code that we could compile and run, instead of just using directives and a non-static Main method. You're very nearly there - it just takes a tiny bit more to be a full [mcve].) Although it looks like more `using` directives are required too.

Comment: Have you heard of [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/)? :-)

Comment: I added two more usings that seem to be default in LinqPad and made the Main method static. Thanks for sharing the improvements.

Comment: Yes, I've heard of LinqPad - but that's not how *most* people develop code. Providing an example which can be copy/paste/compiled as a new project in Visual Studio or any text editor is more useful IMO than just providing using directives and a method. It's only a matter of adding a class declaration, but it's a matter of trying to make your question as easy as possible for people to help you with. Why would you *not* want to do that?

Comment: https://github.com/kevin-montrose/Sigil/issues/51

Comment: @DaisyShipton You're right of course. I totally forgot about adding a class. MWE should be complete now. LinqPad really should provide a way to copy everything needed to the clipboard :-)

Comment: @DaisyShipton I created a UserVoice for LinqPad. Vote [here](https://linqpad.uservoice.com/forums/18302-linqpad-feature-suggestions/suggestions/34193995-add-abiltiy-to-copy-minimum-working-example-mwe) if you want

Comment: Yup, that's definitely better - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like at the moment, *at least* `Sigil.NonGeneric` doesn't handle this properly. However, it also looks like you can mix and match Sigil with non-Sigil code.

So you can change *just* your `ctorBuilder2` code to use the built-in Reflection.Emit code:

```
var ctorBuilder2 = test.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public,
    CallingConventions.Standard, new Type[0]);
var generator = ctorBuilder2.GetILGenerator();
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "arg1");
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, ctor1);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

That then seems to build the assembly as desired.